# Free module over local ring $R$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, flatness, local-rings

People often say that a module $M$ over a not necessarily neotherian local ring $R$ being projective is flat, and also free. However, some refer to the finitely-generatedness of $M$, i.e. $M$ being generated by $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ with $n < \infty$ over $R$. Then I would like to ask that when ${\mathrm{Spec}}\,R[X] \to {\mathrm{Spec}}\,R$ is flat, as it is, the affine ring $R[X]$ is flat over $R$. In this case, am I to think that the free decomposition
$$
R[X] = R \oplus RX\oplus RX^2 \ldots,
$$
which is necessarily of *infinite* length?

I have never seen any reference referring to this infiniteness. To the best of my knowledge, $R[X]$ is flat over *any* ring $R$, though.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.